# Overloading a C++ template class virtual function

Tags: c++, function, templates, virtual, overloading

Below is the code to recreate the problem I am having. `Base` class is a template class with the virtual function `foo`. `foo` has a default implementation that adds the passed in arguments.

`SimpleDerived` derives from `Base`, specializing it with `std::string`. `SimpleDerived` overloads the virtual `Base<T>::foo()` function. This class compiles fine and its `foo` outputs as expected when called in `main`.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct Base
{
    virtual void foo(T val)
    {
        T local = val + val;    // THE OFFENDING LINE OF CODE
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }   
};

struct SimpleDerived : public Base<std::string>
{
    virtual void foo(std::string val)
    {
        std::cout << "SimpleDerived" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct SimpleObject
{
    int value;
};

struct ComplexDerived : public Base<SimpleObject>
{
    virtual void foo(SimpleObject val)
    {
        std::cout << "ComplexDerived" << std::endl;
    }   
};

int main(void)
{
    Base<int> base;
    base.foo(2);

    SimpleDerived simpleDerived;
    simpleDerived.foo("hello world");

    SimpleObject object;
    ComplexDerived complexDerived;
    complexDerived.foo(object);

    return 0;
}
```

`ComplexDerived` derives from `Base`, specializing it with a custom struct `SimpleObject`. `ComplexDerived` overloads `foo` as well. However, this is the root of the problem. If I try to compile this I get:

```
quicktest.cpp: In member function ‘void Base<T>::foo(T) [with T = SimpleObject]’:
quicktest.cpp:47:1:   instantiated from here
quicktest.cpp:8:19: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘val + val’
```

Obviously, there is no operator "+" for `SimpleObject`. But here is my confusion.. the compiler is being asked to implement `Base<SimpleObject>::foo` because this is what `ComplexDerived` inherits from. However, I never use or call `Base<SimpleObject>::foo`. So should the compiler be trying to generate this base class function?

Comment: You may already know this, but since the answers seem to confirm that the compiler will try to instantiate the virtual function in your base class: You can work around the problem using template specializations (making the function pure virtual).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Paragraph 14.7.1/10 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a member template, a non-virtual
>   member function, a member class, or a static data member of a class template that does not require instantiation. **It is unspecified whether or not an implementation implicitly instantiates
>   a virtual member function of a class template if the virtual member function would not otherwise be instantiated.** [...]

In other words, the behavior in this case is implementation-specific.

While in theory the compiler *could* figure out that the call to the base class's implementation of `foo()` won't ever be invoked (since the function call does not occur through a reference or pointer) and avoid instantiating it, this behavior is not mandated by the Standard.

Comment: Thanks Andy! Just fyi, I was using g++ ((Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3).